# Attempting to create a state machine (?) in c# and monogame to change the menu

Tags: c#, monogame

for a computer science project, i decided to do a poker game using monogame. i havent gotten too far and have gotten stuck on how to implement a fully working menu. i followed a tutorial on how to do game states (https://www.trccompsci.online/mediawiki/index.php/Game_states) and edited it to try to make it work for a menu system. it loads the main menu and allows me to click the exit button which quits the game however as soon as i press the button to change to the other menu screen i have implemented, it stops the program with the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

gameState was null.
```

i have absolutely NO clue how to fix this and i am nowhere near smart enough to figure it out for myself. below is the file which contains the code to construct the menu and the line the error occurs is "gameState.CurrentGameState = GameStates.MainMenu;"

```
namespace PokerGameNEA.UI
{
    partial class mainMenu: Panel
    {
        private GameState.Game gameState;
        public void BuildUI()
        {
            var label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "POKER";
            label1.Font = MyraEnvironment.DefaultAssetManager.Load<SpriteFontBase>("IyPZIZAmLtaftSwqk3gBCKNd.ttf.fnt");
            label1.TextAlign = FontStashSharp.RichText.TextHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label1.HorizontalAlignment = Myra.Graphics2D.UI.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            _playButton = new MenuItem();
            _playButton.Text = "PLAY";
            _playButton.Id = "_playButton";
            _playButton.Selected += (s, a) =>
            {
                gameState.CurrentGameState = GameStates.MainMenu;
            };
```

(the rest of the code is just for the rest of that menu, nothing that could be causing problems)

here is the code for the state machine:

```
namespace PokerGameNEA.States
{
    public class GameState
    {
        public enum GameStates
        {
            MainMenu,
            HowToPlay,
            EndOfGame,
        }
        public class Game
        {
            public Desktop _desktop;
            private mainMenu mainMenu;
            private howToPlay howToPlay;
            private Game gameState;

            public void Initialize()
            {
                mainMenu = new mainMenu();
                howToPlay = new howToPlay();
                _desktop = new Desktop();
                _desktop.Root = mainMenu;

                gameState = new GameState.Game();
            }

            // creates a property to store the current game state
            public GameStates CurrentGameState { get; set; }

            // constructor to initialize the game state
            public Game()
            {
                // sets the initial game state
                CurrentGameState = GameStates.MainMenu;
            }

            // Method to update the game state
            public void UpdateGameState()
            {
                // update the game state based on some condition or user input
                // for example, change to HowToPlay when the user selects a "How to Play" option
                // CurrentGameState = GameStates.HowToPlay;
            }

            // Example method to perform actions based on the current game state
            public void PerformActionsBasedOnState()
            {
                switch (CurrentGameState)
                {
                    case GameStates.MainMenu:
                        _desktop.Root = mainMenu;
                        break;

                    case GameStates.HowToPlay:
                        _desktop.Root = howToPlay;
                        break;

                    case GameStates.EndOfGame:
                        _desktop.Root = howToPlay;
                        break;

                    default:
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                }
            }

            public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                _desktop.Render();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

it should just load the new screen however it just crashes and i dont know what to do about it!! i have tried another ways of doing this however they also did not work (it is a MUCH worse way of doing it). i have been stuck at this step for a while now and i do not know at all how to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated and if people want me to provide any further details then i would appreciate it MASSIVELY.

Comment: `private GameState.Game gameState;` where is this `GameState` and its `Game` initialized? did i miss `new GameState()` somewhere..?

Comment: @BagusTesa, you didnt miss it! i assume i should add that after  "private GameState.Game gameState; " in the mainMenu class? this is my first time coding a project like this, so if i seem inexperienced with coding then thats why :)))

Comment: im not sure about [tag:monogame] but try changing your `private GameState.Game gameState;` with `private GameState gameState = new GameState();` given in its original state it most likely will hit null pointer error as you havent assign the `GameState` but tries to access `GameState.Game`.

Comment: good news, the error dissapeared and i can now click the buttons without the program crashing, however when clicking the button nothing actually happens. i changed "gameState.CurrentGameState = GameStates.MainMenu;" to "gameState.CurrentGameState = GameStates.HowToPlay;" and added a method which should update each frame and check if the previous gamestate is different and if it is, it SHOULD change to the new screen however it does not and just kind of does nothing

Comment: not sure why, but your `Draw` methods looks different compared to the link you provided and i cant find any relevant part of the code that draws the current state into the game window. did i miss a couple of lines? anyway, a different question should be asked on a different post to avoid chains of problems..

Comment: the draw method is different to the link provided because im using myra which handles menu creation and whatnot.  _desktop.Root = mainMenu; sets it to the main menu and _desktop.Render() actually renders it. im fairly sure its not myra thats causing issues however if it seems it is i can check it out. im mostly concerned if its my logic in the state machine thats causing it but if nothing seems off then ill have a look at myra